# Show that the system of equations can obtain any chosen values strictly between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We are given the following system of equations:

$E_{1}=a\cdot b\cdot \frac{\sin \beta_1}{2}$

$E_{2}=(b+c)\cdot \frac{\sin \beta_{2}}{2}$

$E_{3}=d\cdot \frac{\sin \gamma_1}{2}$

$E_{4}=(d+e)\cdot(1-a)\cdot \frac{\sin \gamma_2}{2}$

Here we have the following additional information on the parameters:

$\beta_1+\beta_2=\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma_{1}+\gamma_{2}=\frac{\pi}{3}$, $0<a<1$, $0<b+c<1$ and $0<d+e<1$. I am trying to show that we can assign $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ in any chosen manner such that $E_1+E_2+E_3+E_4=\alpha$ for some  fixed $\alpha\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and this would satisfy the above equations. If not, I would like to see a counterexample.

Something I thought was to start by fixing one of the equations to be some value in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ but it seems like this might become challenging very easily (the goal here would be to show that by fixing one, you can achieve different values strictly between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ with the following equation and so on). Certainly all of the equations are continuous, which definitely will be useful.

Comment: Where do these equations come from?

Comment: It's a geometric problem originally that is extremely tedious and difficult to explain on its own, so I would like to leave the geometric setting out of this and just simply think about these equations.

Comment: I count thirteen quantities,  with some  inequality constraints, and you wish to impose that the sum of the $E_i$ be $\alpha.$ If that is the only thing imposed, it seems unlikely that no matter what values the thirteen quantities have, all your equations will happen to hold. Not clear what you're solving for...

Comment: Notice that $E_i>0$ suffices since $\|E\|_1=\alpha<0.5$. Just to be on the safe side: It's fine if I choose $b,\beta_1<0$ or $d,\gamma_1<0$?

Comment: Ok, I'm really not sure what the question is. Can you please clarify the following? State the fixed numbers and their possible values. State the numbers to be determined (from a range of possible values). My current understanding is that you want me to give you a map $\alpha\mapsto(a,b,c,d,e,\beta_1,\beta_2,\gamma_1,\gamma_2)$ that is consistent with all constraints, meaning that the answer by Dosidis is probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

We can start by allowing the parameters to be zero (which is an easier version of the problem at hand).

Choosing $a=c=d=0$, $\beta_1=\beta_2 = \gamma_1 = \gamma_2= \frac{\pi}{6}$ we have $E_1=E_3=0$ and $E_2 = \frac{b}{4}$, $E_4 = \frac{e}{4}$. Then $E_1+ E_2 + E_3+ E_4 = \alpha$ gives us $b+e = 4\alpha$. Therefore $b=e=2\alpha \in(0,1)$ is enough and all of the inequalities would be satisfied (if the inequalities weren't strict).

Instead of setting $a,c,d$ to zero, let $0<\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}$ be a small number to be determined momentarily. Then if we set $a=c=d=\varepsilon$, we have

$$E_1 =  \varepsilon \frac{b}{4}, \, E_2 = \frac{(b+\varepsilon)}{4},\,E_3 =  \frac{\varepsilon}{4},\, E_4 =  (e+\varepsilon)\frac{1-\varepsilon}{4}.$$

Then the condition $E_1+ E_2 + E_3+ E_4 = \alpha$ gives
$$b(1+\varepsilon) + e(1-\varepsilon) = 4\alpha - 3\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2.$$

As before, we set the two qualities on the left to be equal to each other and we get $$ b=\frac{2\alpha - \frac{3\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2}2}{1+\varepsilon}  \quad \text{and} \quad e=\frac{2\alpha - \frac{3\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2}2}{1-\varepsilon}. $$

The inequalities $a\in(0,1)$, and $E_1,E_3\in (0,\frac12)$ are then obviously satisfied. We are left with two inequalities, namely $0<b+c<1$ and $0<d+e<1$, since these would also imply that $E_2,E_4\in(0,\frac12)$. Substituting and doing some algebra we are obtain

$$0<2\alpha - \frac{3}{2}(\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2) < 1 \quad \text{and} \quad 0< 2\alpha + \frac{1}{2} (\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2) < 1. $$

Two of the four inequalities are satisfied trivially: $2\alpha - \frac{3}{2}(\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2) < 2\alpha <1$ and $2\alpha + \frac{1}{2} (\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2)> 2\alpha >0$ (since $\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2>0$ because $\varepsilon <1$). We then have the following two inequalities

$$\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 < \frac{4}3\alpha \quad \text{and} \quad \varepsilon - \varepsilon^2 < 2- 4\alpha, $$
the first of which is relevant when $\alpha$ is close to zero and the second when $\alpha$ is close to $\frac12$.

Since $0<\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}$, we have (in particular) $\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 <2 \varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2 < \varepsilon$ and therefore, it would be enough to choose any
$$\varepsilon < \min\left\{\frac23\alpha,\, 2 - 4\alpha\right\}$$
and set $a,b,c,d,e$ as above and $\beta_1=\beta_2=\gamma_1=\gamma_2 = \frac{\pi}{6}$. Of course from the computations above it is clear that this is not the only choice.